# Windows 8.1 prism and many modules

Tags: c#, prism, windows-8.1

I need to implement Prism in many modules in Windows 8.1 app. I have created Module and Main project. 
In module I have class named MainPage wchich inherits from VisualStateAwarePage.
I need to run this:
NavigationService.Navigate("Main", null);

But I am getting error that I don`t have View with this name. 
Full error is Here:

```
System.ArgumentException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2147024809
  Message=The page name Main does not have an associated type in namespace PrismApp1.Views
Parameter name: pageToken
```

I have added reference to module.
What can I do with this?

Comment: Sulima, regarding **Prism for Windows Runtime** documentation, it explains that the **GetPageType** strategy which look for the pages with the Page word on its name, these Pages would need to be defined on the Main project under the Views folder. You can check the **GetPageType** implementation on the **MVVMAppBase.cs** class. Try moving those Pages to the Main project. Documentation: [Navigating between pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xx130640.aspx#Navigation). Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I would say your problem comes from fact that your view is not in .Views.
I personally prefer to have Pages sub-namespace and hence from time to time I run into that error too. I've solved it like:

```
protected override Task OnInitializeAsync(IActivatedEventArgs args)
 {
     _container.RegisterInstance(NavigationService);
     ViewModelLocationProvider.SetDefaultViewModelFactory(vmType => _container.Resolve(vmType));
     ViewModelLocationProvider.SetDefaultViewTypeToViewModelTypeResolver(viewType =>
     {
          var viewModelTypeName = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "Application.Pages.{0}ViewModel, Application, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral", viewType.Name);
          var viewModelType = Type.GetType(viewModelTypeName);
          return viewModelType;
     });

     return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
}
```

Please be aware that you App must derive from `MvvmAppBase`.

For more inspection you can read [Dave's blogpost](http://www.davidbritch.com/2013/06/changing-default-conventions-used-in.html).